# "Python not found" after VSCode upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode 1.52.1 to work with Python 3.9.1 and Django.

I had to upgrade VSCode to 1.71.0 and when I run Django, I get the following error:

[VSCode terminal error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wykQH.png)

Nothing changed with Python. Software installed, paths are the same. Do I need to change the JSON configuration file?

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: try to run through cmd instead of powershell

Answer (score 0):

try to run through cmd instead of powerShell, or try python3 manage.py runserver

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to run inside VSCode

Comment: Python3 gave exactly the same error

Comment: yes you can run cmd inside vscode by clicking the down arrow in top right of terminal tab

Comment: Great. It worked. But why can I not use the Power Shell? What changed and what impacts will this have by only being able to use cmd?

Comment: Check python path environment variables, sometimes just restarting the system will fix this

Comment: In fact, restarted and used the POWERSHELL with "py manage.py runserver". It worked! Thank you